# Form-control will not adjust size of input

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking to create a simple signup form, but for some reason with my code the input does not adapt to bootstraps form-control-lg class so it will not match the size of my button when I am using default bootstrap CSS, can anyone help?

```
    <div class="container">
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row col-md-5">
        <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="url" placeholder="Your Site URL">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" id="urlInput">TRY IT NOW</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the input-lg class to your input

```
<input class="form-control input-lg" type="url" placeholder="Your Site URL">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using form-group-lg on the parent div instead

```html
<div class="form-group form-group-lg">
        <div class="row col-md-5">
        <input class="form-control" type="url" placeholder="Your Site URL">
        </div>
</div>
```